# What is the replacement method to use for the deprecated codenameone getTitleArea

Tags: codenameone

I am looking for the alternative method replacement for (deprecated)getTitleArea() method as it is widely used in the MaterialScreensUIKit demo

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't used we just set it's UIID but don't do anything risky which is the reason for the deprecation. The `Toolbar` class is where most of the functionality is placed now.